# Can't open/create .db file with SQLite in Visual Studio (UWP, C++)

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, c++-cli, uwp

I have created a blank universal app in Visual Studio 2015 and added just a button to the `MainPage`. Then, I created the click event handler for the button: `myButton_Click(...)`. There I have the following code:

```
void MyTestApp::MainPage::myButton_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    sqlite3 *testDB;
    int result = sqlite3_open("file:///C:/Users/MyName/Downloads/testDB.db", &testDB);
    myButton->Content = result.ToString();
}
```

As you can see I just try to create a new db file and the result of the `sqlite3_open()` function is displayed on the button. Unfortunately, I always get `Code 14: SQLITE_CANTOPEN`.

In Visual Studio I have installed "SQLite for Universal Windows Platform" via Tools -> Extensions and Updates. Under the solutions explorer I added the SQLite for UWP to the References and also included the `<sqlite3.h>` header.

Do I have to assign any special permissions to the app so that it can create files or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UWP apps can't read outside of their own private locations by default - see [file access for UWP in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx).

You can access locations outside of your private storage area using the `StorageFile` APIs, but they won't work for SQLite which expects a filename. There is currently no way to do this other than to copy the database to your local storage area first.

Comment: Thank you. Your link gave me some new informations I did not know before. I took the insallation folder now using the ```InstalledLocation``` from your link and got the ```AppX``` directory inside my VS project. I've modified my code to ```int result = sqlite3_open("testDB.db", &testDB);``` but again I got Code 14. I also tried the complete path ```file:///C:/.../AppX/testDB.db```, again Code 14. However, under the AppData location using ```sqlite3_open("file:///C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Packages/.../testDB.db", &testDB);``` I got SQLITE_OK. But no ```testDB.db``` file was created there...

Comment: `InstalledLocation` is read-only. Use `ApplicationData.Current` to get the local folder. Also there's no need to use the "file:///" syntax.

Answer (score 1):

With Peter Torr's comments it finally worked:

```
void MyTestApp::MainPage::myButton_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ f = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;

    sqlite3 *testDB;
    int result = sqlite3_open_v2("C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Packages/538ec661-2ebf-4c45-8845-3a4cb6afd397_4jdacjwc0e74a/LocalState/testDB.db", &testDB, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);

    //This works too:
    //int result = sqlite3_open_v2("C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\538ec661-2ebf-4c45-8845-3a4cb6afd397_4jdacjwc0e74a\\LocalState\\testDB.db", &testDB, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);

    myButton->Content = result.ToString();
    //myButton->Content = f->Path;

    sqlite3_close(testDB);
}
```

The `testDB.db` is now available at the directory you see in the code. I've tried a similar code before, but it did not work. It seems the flags `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` made the difference...